# ProFTPD DisplayLogin not showing?

Tags: linux, ftp, proftpd

In my config I have set `DisplayLogin` to `/etc/welcome.msg` and inside `welcome.msg` set a welcome message and saved it. I then restart the ProFTPD service, go to connect via FileZilla and the message is not shown at all.

All I get is:

```
Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Directory listing of "/home/UserName" successful
```

The file permission for the `welcome.msg` is 0644. I tried to search on Google but found nothing on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FileZilla does not display the FTP welcome message.

Actually many GUI FTP clients do not.